# How to disable main window (and show it) while another form is open?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create two Forms:

Form1 - The main form

Form2 - The username and password form

Is it possible to show both forms (while disabling Form1) like this?:

[image: Example]

I'm also trying to send Form2 a Boolean value to determine if the log-in was successful or not. And it works:

**Form1**:

```
bool loginValid = false;

private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Login loginForm = new(loginValid);
    LoginForm.Show();
}
```

**Form2**:

```
private bool _loginValid;

public Login(bool loginValid)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _loginValid = loginValid;
}
```

So two things:

1. How do I show AND disable Form1 until Form2 sends it a `bool` value of `True`?
2. I'm able to send Form2 data from Form1. How do I send back data from Form2 back to Form1?

Everything I tried is already typed up top.

Comment: Use LoginForm.ShowDialog() instead of Show()

Comment: @AJITH That displays only the Login form. I want both forms to show (if that makes any sense).

Comment: Use Form1's `Shown` event of instead of `Load` and show Form2 with `ShowDialog()` (declare Form2 with an `using` statement) -- Add a public `bool` Property to Form2 that indicates the state of the procedure it handles. Read that value in Form1 when Form2 closes

Comment: @Jimi Can you give me an example? I'm still new to coding and am practicing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to show another form the Load event of the form. Instead you can use the Shown event and call the ShowDialog() as shown below.

```
private void Main_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Login loginForm = new(loginValid);
    LoginForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: That is what I have. But, only the Log-in form shows until it is closed. I want both windows opened at the same time, if that makes any sense.

Comment: The code which you shared is using Load() event.The above code which I shared uses Shown() event. Load occurs before displaying the form whereas Shown occurs after displaying the form.

Comment: I know. I changed it to .ShowDialog() from .Show(), but it only shows the Log-in form.